# Subdomain Proxy/Rewrite with Nginx Proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite

I want to take m.example.com and direct those requests to example.com/mobile/ with nginx. (The same nginx sever will be serving example.com)

Can someone help me with the config I would need? I can post my nginx.conf if needed, but I assume its something like:

location  / {
  rewrite      /([^/] +)  /mobile/$1  break;
  proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
}

Am I in the right ballpark?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a server block for this to allow Nginx to use it's hash table lookup.

```
server {
    server_name m.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ http://example.com/mobile$request_uri permanent;
    }

    location /mobile {
        rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this account for links like m.imax.com/mobile/main? How would I account for that?

Comment: Edited the code example. Now it will rewrite m.example.com/mobile/main and m.example.com/main to example.com/mobile/main